# Element in table cell displayed larger than others of same size on mobile browser

Tags: css

I created this simple below table with 3 cells of width 33% each and all 3 pics in cells display same size in chrome/safari for desktop/laptop but pic3 displays slightly larger size in mobile browsers for smartphones, Chrome/Safari. Used "table-layout: fixed" but it didn't help:

```
.mobTab {
    table-layout:fixed;    
    width: 99%;
}

<table class="mobTab">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 33%; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px"><a><img src="pic1" alt=""/></a></td>
    <td style="width: 33%; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px"><a><img src="pic2" alt=""/></a></td>
    <td style="width: 33%; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px"><a><img src="pic3" alt=""/></a></td>
</tr>
```

Here's the page, [Oliom.com](https://oliom.com/), compare desktop/mobile version to see what I mean, it's the 3 round pics near the bottom.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Do you mean the buttons for "Pick-up"?

Comment: Having difficulty finding the element. Could you be clearer?

Comment: I can't get to the bottom of this but, the padding for that td element is different from the others. That is from inspecting the page,which does not match up with the padding in your question. Maybe some JS is getting applied inconsistently.

Comment: it's the size of pic3 in above code and on the website, oliom.com, the round pic with "vacation rentals" label on. It's displayed larger than others on smartphone

Comment: as a side note - because you have 33% widths your total width is 99% + 50px in padding which means that the table is adjusting the tds regardless of your set widths - without using box-sizing: border-box - attribute for the table you are adding that padding to the widths - so remove the right padding of those td elements and make the widths 33.3333% and center the td contents and check that first...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the 25px of right padding is eating away at some of the width of the first two 's and the third isn't effected by that as it has no padding.

Give each  a left and right padding of 10px, and then apply a negative 10px left and right margin on the parent div to fix the alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, indeed I wasn't compensating for the extra 25px. Yes, sorry the snippet above wasn't the correct one. I reduced it to 10px and it works.